# CodeIgniter 3 - set_header does not work

Tags: http-headers, codeigniter-3, response-headers

This issue occurs when I'm trying to build CORS enabled RESTful API.

When I put this inside my view file (I'm using CodeIgniter)

```
// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    $this->output->set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}", true);
    $this->output->set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true', true);
    $this->output->set_header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400', true);    // cache for 1 day
}
// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        $this->output->set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS", true);         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        $this->output->set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}", true);

}
$this->output->set_header("Content-type: text/x-json", true);
```

None of the code above that sets the header works. Even when I used PHP's own header() function.

I had to set the headers from .htaccess files to make CORS work.

What is the issue here? I'd like to be able to set the headers from CodeIgniter's view file.

Help.

PS : I'm using CI 3.1.2

Comment: Did you try to ob_clean before?

Comment: Yeah I did, but still cannot change headers.

Answer (score 0):

please use something:

```
 $response = (new \CI_Output())
                ->set_status_header(200)
                ->set_header('Content-Type: application/json')
                ->set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')
                ->set_header('Access-Control-Max-Age: ');
            $response->_display();
            session_write_close();
            exit;
```